# how to use mod_dav without having to give apache write permissions

Tags: apache2, mod-dav-svn

We are trying to improve our webserver security and force as many files as possible to have 0644 permissions by root:www-data so Apache only has write permissions to specific directories and files.

The problem is that we run a mod_dav webdav server on the same apache installation that we use to push remote files, via a virtual host so all files updated through that are created/modified as apache's user (www-data in our case).

I know previous Apache versions could assign a different user in vhosts (old assignuserid) via a directive but I understand that on 2.2 versions this is only possible using something like mpm-itk engine (a fork of prefork with support for users on vhosts).

This root sounds a bit too complicated for us in the long term (updates, support for the modules, etc) so we would appreciate any help/suggestions to find other alternatives to either user use or a separate webdav file server .

Comment: It would be a security hazard to allow the Apache process to create a file as the `root` user when it is running as user `www-data`.  Should the files pushed by WebDAV also be made 0644?

Comment: Currently files pushed via webdav are created as the Apache user itself (www-data) with write permissions to the owner. This is what we are trying to avoid by forcing webdav to create as a different owner.

Answer (score 0):

You could run your webdav service using fcgi from Apache. Use one of the many third party webdav servers available such as [this one](http://koti.kapsi.fi/jpa/webdav/).

You can run the fcgi program as root if you want to. Although from a security point of view, that's a pretty bad idea.